# C equivalent to Fortran namelist

Tags: c, variables, file-io, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am used to Fortran in which I used the namelist sequential read in to get variables out of a file. This allows me to have a file which looks like this

```
&inputDataList
n = 1000.0 ! This is the first variable
m = 1e3 ! Second
l = -2 ! Last variable
/
```

where I can name the variable by it's name and assign a value as well as comment afterwards to state what the variable actually is. The loading is done extremely easy by

```
namelist /inputDataList/ n, m, l
open( 100, file = 'input.txt' )
read( unit = 100, nml = inputDataList )
close( 100 )
```

Now my question is, is there any similar thing in C? Or would I have to do it manually by chopping the string at the '=' and so on?

Comment: I'm not familiar with fortran but I've never heard of anything like that in C

Comment: I do not believe C has anything like that; but as a side note, `NAMELIST` does not have to be sequential.

Comment: There is no equivalent in the C language.  Perhaps someone has written   C code to do this ... you could try searching.

Comment: If you already have a Fortran procedure that gets the data from a namelist file, you can call that procedure from a C program. Look into `ISO_C_BINDING` intrinsic module which will let you specify an exact name for the Fortran procedure that a C program will see.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a simple example that will let you read Fortran namelists from C. I used the namelist file that you provided in the question, `input.txt`.

Fortran subroutine `nmlread_f.f90` (notice the use of `ISO_C_BINDING`):

```
subroutine namelistRead(n,m,l) bind(c,name='namelistRead')

  use,intrinsic :: iso_c_binding,only:c_float,c_int
  implicit none

  real(kind=c_float), intent(inout) :: n
  real(kind=c_float), intent(inout) :: m
  integer(kind=c_int),intent(inout) :: l

  namelist /inputDataList/ n,m,l

  open(unit=100,file='input.txt',status='old')
  read(unit=100,nml=inputDataList)
  close(unit=100)

  write(*,*)'Fortran procedure has n,m,l:',n,m,l

endsubroutine namelistRead
```

C program, `nmlread_c.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void namelistRead(float *n, float *m, int *l);

int main()
{
  float n;
  float m;
  int   l;

  n = 0;
  m = 0;
  l = 0;

  printf("%5.1f %5.1f %3d\n",n,m,l);

  namelistRead(&n,&m,&l);

  printf("%5.1f %5.1f %3d\n",n,m,l);   
}
```

Also notice that `n`,`m` and `l` need to be declared as pointers in order to pass them by reference to the Fortran routine.

On my system I compile it with Intel suite of compilers (my gcc and gfortran are years old, don't ask):

```
ifort -c nmlread_f.f90
icc -c nmlread_c.c
icc nmlread_c.o nmlread_f.o /usr/local/intel/composerxe-2011.2.137/compiler/lib/intel64/libifcore.a
```

Executing `a.out` produces the expected output:

```
  0.0   0.0   0
 Fortran procedure has n,m,l:   1000.000       1000.000              -2
1000.0 1000.0  -2
```

You can edit the above Fortran procedure to make it more general, e.g. to specify namelist file name and list name from the C program.

Answer (score 4):

I've made a test of above answer under GNU compilers v 4.6.3 and worked perfectly for me. Here's is what I did for the corresponding compilation:

```
gfortran -c nmlread_f.f90
gcc -c nmlread_c.c
gcc nmlread_c.o nmlread_f.o -lgfortran
```

Comment: I do not see a reason why a C and Fortran code  would not work with GCC. Why not just `gfortran nmlread_f.f90 nmlread_c.c` ?