# Error linking fortran subroutine into c++ program

Tags: c++, linker, fortran90

I am in the processes of converting a program from Fortran to C++.  To maintain input compatibility, however, I am using subroutines and Fortran's namelist functionality following the instructions [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17581416/847795).  Since this is a legacy code, the namelist I am working on is a bit more ridiculous with 30+ variables.  Everything works up until linking when I get the error:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x2732): undefined reference to `readDatainMesh(double*, int*, int*, double*, char*, double*, char*, int*, int*, int*, double*, int*, int*, int*, double*, double*, double*, int*, int*, int*, int*, double*, double*, double*, double*, int*, int*, double*, int*, int*, double*, char*, double*, double*, double*, int*, double*, double*, double*, int*, int*, int*, char*, char*, double*, double*)'
```

I have the following input files:

readNamelists.f90:

```
 subroutine readDatainMesh(...) &
        bind(c, name='readDatainMesh')
        use,intrinsic :: iso_c_binding,only:c_double,c_int,c_char
        implicit none

        real(kind=c_double),    intent(inout) :: realVars
        integer(kind=c_int),    intent(inout) :: intVars
        character(kind=c_char), intent(inout) :: charVars
        .
        .
        .    

     namelist/datain_mesh/...

         open(unit = 100, file = 'input.nam', status = 'old')
         read(unit = 100, nml = datain_mesh)
         close(unit = 100)

 endsubroutine readDatainMesh
```

which I compile with `gfortran -Wall -o readNamelists.o -c readNamelists.f90`.  This produces warnings about unused dummy variables, but that is all.

I have a C header for the function, which I have checked against both the called function in main.cpp and the fortran implementation.  It looks like:

```
#ifndef READNAMELISTS_H
#define READNAMELISTS_H

void readDatainMesh(...);

#endif
```

I call `gcc -Wall -o main.o -c main.cpp` which gives no warnings.  Then finally `gcc -Wall -o main main.o readNamelists.o -lstdc++ -lgfortran` which throws the above error.  I thought that perhaps the symbols werent matching so I ran `nm` on both object files and the lines of interest are:

```
0000000000000000 T readDatainMesh
```

and

```
             U _Z14readDatainMeshPdPiS0_S_PcS_S1_S0_S0_S0_S_S0_S0_S0_S_S_S_S0_S0_S0_S0_S_S_S_S_S0_S0_S_S0_S0_S_S1_S_S_S_S0_S_S_S_S0_S0_S0_S1_S1_S_S_
```

which obviously don't match.  My question is how to I resolve this?

Comment: have you tried to add `extern "C"` before function declaration? The problem is in mangling and different call convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_Z14readDatainMeshPdPiS0_S_PcS_S1_S0_S0_S0_S_S0_S0_S0_S_S_S_S0_S0_S0_S0_S_S_S_S_S0_S0_S_S0_S0_S_S1_S_S_S_S0_S_S_S_S0_S0_S0_S1_S1_S_S_` is the C++ mangled name including the parameter types. This way the C++ compiler can give overloaded functions different symbols and distinguish them.

One can demangle it from command line:

```
$ echo _Z14readDatainMeshPdPiS0_S_PcS_S1_S0_S0_S0_S_S0_S0_S0_S_S_S_S0_S0_S0_S0_S_S_S_S_S0_S0_S_S0_S0_S_S1_S_S_S_S0_S_S_S_S0_S0_S0_S1_S1_S_S_ | demangle
readDatainMesh(double*, int*, int*, double*, char*, double*, char*, int*, int*, int*, double*, int*, int*, int*, double*, double*, double*, int*, int*, int*, int*, double*, double*, double*, double*, int*, int*, double*, int*, int*, double*, char*, double*, double*, double*, int*, double*, double*, double*, int*, int*, int*, char*, char*, double*, double*)
```

You therefore have to tell the C++ compiler to treat this as C function without overloading. This can be done using `extern "C"`. If the same header is used from C and C++code you also need a guard, as `extern "C"` is not valid in C.

in full the header might look like this:

```
#ifndef READNAMELISTS_H
#define READNAMELISTS_H

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void readDatainMesh(...);
#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

In case you do C++ only and that's the only function you can shorten it to

```
#ifndef READNAMELISTS_H
#define READNAMELISTS_H

extern "C" void readDatainMesh(...);

#endif
```