# C++ equivalent to Fortran Namelist

Tags: c++, data-structures, file-io, fortran, dataformat

My question is nearly-identical to [C equivalent to Fortran namelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581416/c-equivalent-to-fortran-namelist)

The key difference is that I'm using C++/17 and wanted to know if there is a more C++ idiomatic manner of solving the issue.

Comment: What *is* a namelist?

Comment: Its a file input, the linked question has an example of one

Comment: Oh, interesting. Didn’t the accepted answer work for you?

Comment: It would, but I was hoping there would be a more elegant c++-way of handling the issue

Comment: Is the data combined in your namelist just an ad-hoc assembly of unrelated values,  or could it be seen as a kind of structured object ?

Comment: More of an ad-hoc assembly of unrelated values. The variable cannot just be anything. The values (e.g. n, m, l in the example) are defined in the program in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [boost::program_options](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/program_options.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent to Fortran's [Namelist](http://www.lahey.com/docs/lfpro78help/F95ARNAMELISTStmt.htm) in C++.  And there is no portable way of achieving this.

If you want to achieve a similar construct, you'd need some general parsing function working with lines on an `istream`:

- It would read lines and ignore anything following a `"!"`;
- It would read the name that follows the first `"&"` to see if it matches the expected name;
- It would stop reading when encountering a sole `"/"` on a line;
- It would parse every line in-between, finding the a string with the name of the variable, the `"="`, and a string with the value on the right of the equal operator, and store the two strings in a [`std::map<std::string,std::string>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

For ad hoc reading, you'd call the parsing function to transform `istream` lines into the `map`.  You would then access the map to initialise the variables.  An easy and powerful way would be to use a `stringstream sst(my_map["variable name"]); sst>>my_variable;`

If the Namelist would correspond more or less to a `class` or a `struct` `X`,  the idiom would then be to overload a `friend istream& operator>> (istream&, X&);`.  This overloaded extractor would then work as in the ad-hoc case to initialise the member variables.

Of course, I simplify somewhat the algorithm, since you'd also need to cope with errors in the input file: what do you do if an expected variable is missing ?  what do you do if the value read is incompatible with the target variable ?

If you are migrating Fortran code to C++ and you must to use Namelist to avoid disruptions, this could be a portable way to go forward.

But if it's just an habit of yours, and the file format is not mandatory, then you may consider using [json](https://json.org), with one of the many libraries existing to read and write this format (22 libraries are listed on the linked page). The advantage is that you don't have to reinvent the wheel, you'd be more interopearble with a lot of other languages, and json seems more future-proof.

Comment: Is there any json library that would be considered 'standard' for c++. If not, is there one that is known for its greatest simplicity for new users.

Comment: @DanielMarchand [Json for modern c++](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) has a very nice design that makes it almost as easy to use as containers in the standard library.  Alternatively, there is the header-only [rapidJSON](https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson).  I have not found more recent [benchmark](https://github.com/miloyip/nativejson-benchmark) but rapidjson was a long time the fastest parser (in the benchmark graphs, Json for modern c++ appears under Nlohmann).

Comment: Json looks nice but it seems it does not support comments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-comments-be-used-in-json They are use in Fortran namelists *a lot*.

Comment: @VladimirF True! But there are a couple of workarounds, like for example some comment fields that can be ignored (or processed if one day it turns out that the comments could add value to the app). Of course, if comments are one of the main feature and the json style to cope with them makes the format less readable, then the initially proposed approach would be the better alternative (at the cost of cross language interoperability).